# Cms page (or static block) inside product description

Tags: product, cms, static-block

I need to add some static content inside the product description.

I have a store where I bulk add all my products via CSV import and many of them share common HTML code in the description field, for example, the model description.

Let's say that I have 500 products model XYZ and the XYZ description is

```
<h1>XYZ</h1>
<p>The next generation of XY<p>
```

is there a way to create this as a cms page (or static block) and insert it in the description of the products?

I could have it done editing the layout of the product page, but I want it in the description so I can easily sync it with eBay and other markets.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I don't recommend it because this may lead to performance issues (more time needed for processing the product description), I wrote a tutorial on how to do this. [You can find it here.](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2010/01/problem-add-static-block-to-product.html)
It worked for me for products and categories without a problem.
The main idea is to process the product description (or any other attribute) just like the content of a CMS page or a CMS block is processed before returning the content. I mean It should be able to support directives like `{{block type="..."}}`, `{{store url=""}}`, `{{skin}}` and others.

Answer (score 5):

From any CMS field in Magento you should be able to refer to a static block - you can even refer to it programmatically:

**Adding Static and non-static blocks directly to templates:**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('cms/block')
->setBlockId('your_block_id')->toHtml(); ?>
```

**Short code inside another block or cms page :**

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="your_block_id"}}
```

Some more reading:

http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/web/magento-static-blocks/

<sub>Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007555/how-to-add-a-cms-static-block-to-all-pages-in-magento</sub>